# How to handle redirect back to Laravel website from payment portal

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and I am currently testing using VS Code on my local machine(http). I am testing integrating a payment portal into my application. I am able to process the transaction on the payment portal(https). When the transaction is completed a redirect to my application's "thank you" page is triggered, but this is not successful. Instead it is redirecting to the login page?

I have tried excluding the CSRF protection for this specific uri's.

```
protected $except = [
 'webhook/*'
];
```

I would expect to be directed to the "thank you" page once the transaction has been processed on the payment portal. Instead being directed to the login page.

Comment: This is happening because of session of your application. not from CSRF.

Comment: There should be a redirectURL for you to define in the payment portal that you're integrating, is it the url to your "thank you" page?

Comment: Yes, the redirectURL in the payment portal is pointing to my "thank you" page.

Comment: If the issue is caused by Sessions in Laravel, can you assist with some guidance on how I would proceed in resolving this.